# Using a Form Handle for a Case in a Switch Statement?

Tags: c#, vb6

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how to write this VB code

```
 Case frm.hwnd:
```

in C# so that it will work in a switch statement using a long as a test expression. When I try

```
case (long)frm.Handle:
```

my IDE tells me that I need to use a constant expression. I've tried both casting the form handle into a long and assigning it to a constant long variable

```
const long frmHandle = new (long)frm.Handle;
```

and instantiating an `IntPtr` object to cast into a `long` when I use it as a case expression.

```
const IntPtr frmHandle = new IntPtr(frm.Handle);
```

The former caused an error saying

> the value being assigned must be constant

and the latter caused an error saying

> IntPtr cannot be declared as constant

Is there any way to still use the form handle as a case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use an "if" for this:

```
if(variable == frm.Handle)
```

A switch case is just an better looking if else ;-)

Comment: I'm surprised I didn't see this solution staring me right in the face.

Answer (score 2):

The `switch` statement is used with (compile-time) constant expressions, not variables. You cannot use a window handle with one.

```
const IntPtr frmHandle = new IntPtr(frm.Handle);
```

frmHandle is not a compile time constant. This syntax states that it cannot be changed after it is initialized.

You can achieve the same thing, but with a variable, with a series of `if` statements. Depending on your real needs, you might also use a dictionary using the window handle as a key (the value would depend on what you're trying to achieve here).

Comment: +1 VB `Select Case` has some similarities with C# `switch` but some important differences too. In VB the case value can be a run-time expression but in C# it has to be evaluated at compile-time.